# I am getting an error in django project while submitting the form can any one please tell the correction of my error

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, django, bootstrap-4

**Error**

Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/contact/contact
Using the URLconf defined in portfolio.urls

```
admin/
[name='home']
about/ [name='about']
projects/ [name='projects']
contact/ [name='contact']
The current path, contact/contact, didn't match any of these.
```

**code for the form **

```
<form action="contact" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"  name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
              <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Your Number">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Explain your concern</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="desc" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
          </form>
```

**views.py**

```
def contact(request):
    return render(request,"contact.html")
```

**urls.py**
**this url is from my app**

```
urlpatterns=[
    path("",views.home,name="home"),
    path("about/",views.about,name="about"),
    path("projects/",views.projects,name="projects"),
    path("contact/",views.contact,name="contact"),
]
```

**urls.py**
**this url is from my project**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("",include("home.urls")),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url should propbaly be:  http://localhost:8000/contact/

So change it to blank so will it from current which is a GET request to a POST
request of the current url:
action=""

Propably better to use action="{% url 'contact' %}"
which is your named route contact.